# Awesome Murder Mystery

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, lateral-thinking, mystery

Source: [gpuzzles.com](https://gpuzzles.com/?source=external&stack=1)
[image]
[image]

Note: The owner of [gpuzzles.com](https://gpuzzles.com/?source=external&stack=1) did not allow me to copy the puzzle, However site is fine pasting picture.

Comment: So... You can't copy the puzzles, but you can copy a picture of them? That seems... dubious.

Comment: I've seen this before, but as an (allegedly) true story rather than a puzzle, and (with all due respect to gpuzzles.com) with significantly better grammar.

Comment: @F1Krazy I have *also* seen this before, and it was supposedly invented as a philosophical thought experiment. In any case, I don't think it's a puzzle - the point is to provoke debate, not to have a definite answer.

Comment: What if the son was Alexis? Did he then commit suicide by placing a bullet in a gun which was not intended to kill him?

Comment: @chicharito, you've posted four puzzles on PSE, and every single one has been taken from gpuzzles.com. This is not how PSE is meant to be used. And if "the owner of gpuzzles.com does not allow me to copy the puzzles" then what you have done here is plainly out of order from their perspective as well. **Please stop doing this**.

Comment: In comments on a now-deleted [earlier question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52876/a-classic-puzzle-for-gpuzzles-com) taken from gpuzzles.com and posted here by chicharito, another of the PSE mods wrote this: "Feel free to post your own, original puzzles, but in the future gpuzzles.com content in general, and content prominently promoting them in particular, is no longer appropriate."

Comment: I'm going to give the benefit of the doubt and assume that the deletion meant that you never saw that comment. But, to be absolutely clear, this is an official request that you **stop posting puzzles from gpuzzles.com here**; doing so is likely to have adverse consequences.

Comment: I'm closing this as off-topic because it is taken from another site without their permission, and chicharito needs to stop copying their content to PSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you are looking for is

> Suicide, according to a quick search for the original case

However I don't quite know that this lives up to the spirit of puzzling, as the ruling seems subjective, and can not be deduced purely logically?

Answer (score 2):

All done according to logic stated in question. Actual legal aspects are a different story (I'm thinking manslaughter would be closer than murder)

Alexis:

> Not suicide, since his actions didn't cause his death.

Old man:

> Intended to kill someone, and by his action, killed someone else. Thus, guilty of murder. Note: Didn't pick it up the first time, but the story mentions "only threatening", implying he "knew" the gun was empty. However, he did pull the trigger, which contradicts the threatening.

Son:

> Caused death of Alexis by actions intended to kill someone, thus, guilty of murder.

Answer (score -1):

> I would said it is murder as we can't know for sure he wasn't aware of the safety net. I would charge the shooter for accidental murder