# Gpuzzles Holes Puzzle

Tags: riddle, visual

Source : [Gpuzzles.com](https://gpuzzles.com/?source=stack&external=1)[image]

Can you count the number of holes in the puzzles?

**Note:  Answer is not three**

Comment: I don't know if you're aware of this, but [puzzles from gpuzzles.com aren't allowed to be reposted here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60376/awesome-murder-mystery?rq=1).

Comment: @F1Krazy taken the permission from the owner on mail :-)

Comment: Very well then, I retract my close vote.

Comment: Is the watermark part of the puzzle?

Comment: I think this question is 'too broad' since the answer depends on the state of the back-part of the shirt. Which isn't shown.

Comment: Technically the only right answer to the question is "No."

Comment: Do we also assume that the things that LOOK like holes in the front are actually holes and not something printed on the shirt?

Answer (score 9):

I think there are

> **10 holes.** One for each arm, the bottom and the neck equals 4 holes, plus the three that are through the shirt go through both the front and the back, so that's 6 total. 6 + 4 = 10 holes.

Comment: I think you are almost right - you don't know that there isn't just one big hole in the back. So the answer should be 'at least 8'

Answer (score 3):

> At least 10 - because we can see through it means the 3 holes have matching counterparts on the back (6 in total).  Then we have two holes for the sleeves, one at the neck, one at the bottom (4 in total). Of course the back might be missing which means that we have only 7.

Comment: The back panel could just be one large hole.

Comment: Well, at least 5. The back panel could be missing up to the bottom of the shirt and the arm holes

Comment: @LeppyR64 Well, that's basically what I wrote  - the back could be missing.

Answer (score 3):

> 11. 3 in front, 3 in back, 2 arms, head, base, label (usually double-folded)

Comment: The back panel could just be one large hole.

Comment: Nice one regarding the label 

Comment: @LeppyR64; yeah, and it could have a million holes in it too!

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: Indeed.  It is a bad puzzle.

Answer (score 2):

> 10.
>  3 holes front and back makes 6 plus sleeves, neck and bottom holes

Comment: The back panel could just be one large hole.

Answer (score 2):

There are many possibility.

> **10 hole** : if there are same three hole at back side in t-shirt.
>  
>  3 hole + 2 arm + 1 neck + 1 bottom + 3 hole at back = 10
>  
>  
>  
> **8 hole** : if there is only one big hole at back side in t-shirt. 
>  
>     3 hole + 2 arm + 1 neck + 1 bottom + 1 big hole at back = 8

Comment: There is at least part of a back part, since you can see the label near the neckhole. (Which is often placed at the inside of a shirt, near the neckhole.) I agree with the lower 2 options, but you could also have 2 holes at the back, or many more which aren't visible.

Answer (score 1):

> 6

because

> 3 holes + 2 arms + 1 neck

Comment: Are you sure that those actual holes count as 3 and not 6?

Comment: You can't be certain of either. there could be one big hole in the back, or an insane amount of small ones.
Depending on how the back looks, the answer here appears to be anything from 4 to infity.

Answer (score 1):

> 4, the things on the front are actually part of the tshirt design, it's just a coincidence they look like the background 
>
> either that or 1, the whole t-shirt is actually a hole, that it looks like a t-shirt is actually an optical illusion (it's really a t-shirt shaped whole with a background painted there)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Could you edit your answer to include spoiler tags, so as not to spoil the solution for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves?

Comment: Very original answer!